# GPFdist insert from flat file throws error 'invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00' on insert

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psql, greenplum, data-ingestion

I am facing an issue in a process I am writing to ingest data from a large flat file. I am preprocessing the flat file using a python wrapper with UTF8 specifications as follows:

`wrFile = io.open("outFile","w+",encoding='utf8')`

I am reading the source file line by line using:

`lineACT = linecache.getline("inFile", i+j)
lineNxt = linecache.getline("inFile", i+j+1)`

Further, after pre-processing the lines I am writing the file as follows:
`wrFile.write(lineACT)`
Thus, iterating through the # of lines in the infile, i am creating the outfile.

Now the file is ready to be ingested into an external `postgresql` table using the following query. The loader application is written in `Java` and all the configurations are passed using a properties file:

```
-- CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE FOR A SPECIFIC CLIENT
CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE outTable (  col1 character(3), col2 
character(3),..... )
LOCATION ( '<LocationOf outFile>' )
FORMAT    'CUSTOM' (formatter=fixedwidth_in,col1='3',col2='3'......)
LOG ERRORS INTO errorTable SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 2 ROWS;

-- INSERT INTO DELTA TABLE
INSERT  INTO deltaTable
SELECT  col1, col2,......
FROM    outTable
;

-- DROP EXTERNAL TABLE
DROP  EXTERNAL TABLE IF EXISTS outTable;
```

Running this on a `UNIX` box throws me an exception:

```
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Segment reject limit reached. Aborting operation. Last error was: Expected line size from the formatting string: 1655, but the actual size is: 455  (seg43 slice1 uxpbdpsdw06.dstcorp.net:1028 pid=335160)
```

**Note:** Each line in outFile is 1655 characters. Column structure of both ***outTable*** & ***deltaTable*** are also 1655.
When I check into the errorTable I find this in `errmsg` column:

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

Now, I am guessing that the database is not accepting the `null` characters `'0x00'` in the file because of the encoding properties of the db which I checked is `'UTF8'`

I tried to remove the null chars from the file using the following bash commands:

```
sed 's/\x0/-9/g' outFile > outFile_
```

&

```
tr < outFile -d '\000' > outFile_
```

but nothing has worked till now. Can someone please throw in some suggestion as to how to make this work?

--

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Did you confirm that the "outFile_" has in fact the null bytes removed? Also did you replace the "outFile" with "outFIle_", or change the table to load data from "outFile_"?

Comment: If you're pre-processing in Python, why not strip the null bytes then? `line.replace("\0","")` or whatever, assuming they're otherwise meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this particular error is encountered whenever the data has unprintable character. My recommendation would be to replace the unprintable character with space and execute the query